# VueJs page gives 404 on refresh with django

Tags: python, django, vue.js

I build VueJs app and copy all static files to django static folder and copy vuejs index.html to django templates folder 
but when refresh page it raise 404 
here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>FMS</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" name=viewport>
    <link rel=stylesheet href=https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css
          integrity=sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf crossorigin=anonymous>
    <link href=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css rel=stylesheet>
    <link rel=stylesheet href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css>
    <link rel=stylesheet href=https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
          integrity=sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u crossorigin=anonymous>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons"
              rel=stylesheet>
        <link href="{% static "/css/app.6c7cbd2b6c8e41a0245180734aee4192.css" %}" rel=stylesheet>
    </head>
</head>
<script src=/socket.io/socket.io.js></script>
<body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div id=app></div>
<script>if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1) {
    window.fetch = undefined;
}</script>
<script type=text/javascript src=./src/main.js></script>
<script src=https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js
        integrity=sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo
        crossorigin=anonymous></script>
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js
        integrity=sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1
        crossorigin=anonymous></script>
<script src=https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
        integrity=sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa
        crossorigin=anonymous></script>
<script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js></script>
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.2/socket.io.js></script>
<script type=text/javascript src="{% static "/js/manifest.e9739da6f5c27d585419.js" %}"></script>
<script type=text/javascript src="{% static "/js/vendor.7deff2a26292e503ec19.js" %}"></script>
<script type=text/javascript src="{% static "/js/app.bc1afe162faeb2a6bfa3.js" %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which URL do you visit? And how did you define your `urls`, `view` and `settings` in Django?

Comment: **url** : `http://localhost:8080/table/customer` **vuejs router**
and my urls :
 `urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include('fms.urls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', UserLoginView),
    path('test-login/', UserTestLoginView),
    path('',view=TemplateView.as_view(template_name='../templates/index.html')),
   path('doc/', schema_view)
]`

Comment: Please add it to the initial post and include the error traceback

Comment: when i change debug to false it works successfully